# Using input checkbox for collapsible content. I need some links embedded within the p tag but I can't select it. Any ideas for a fix?

Tags: html, css

This is intended to be for a FAQ page.

I need to have links to be clickable in the 'answer' portion but it only functions as a toggle to show and hide the content.

Maybe there's another alternative for this? I didn't want to use details and summary tags because of their lack of compatibility for other modern browsers.

```css
article {position: relative;}

input[type=checkbox] {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   opacity: 0;
}

article label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: #008349;
  font-size: 25px;

}

article label:before {
 content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 7px solid black;
 border-top: 7px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
 margin: 0 20px 2px 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ h3 label:before {
 border-left: 7px solid transparent;
 border-top: 7px solid black;
 border-right: 7px solid transparent;

}

p {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 30px;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease;
  font-size: 15px; 
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: left;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ h3 ~ p {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
        <article>
            <input type="checkbox" id="faq-1">
            <h3><label for="faq-1">Question?</label></h3>
            <p>This is my answer, but I also want a clickable <a href="http://www.google.com">link</a> here.</p>
        </article>
```

Comment: Couldn't you remove the height on `input[type=checkbox]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkbox is covering the whole article because of this:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

If you just hide it:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
```

The whole thing works as intended.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wk0bqkLr/6/)

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution I came up with on my own. Awesome!